# how to read XML file and change some value

Tags: c#, xml

Xml file :

```xml
<configuration>
    <work.config>
        <variable name="A" value="001" />
        <variable name="B" value="002" />
        <variable name="C" value="003" />
    </work.config>
</configuration>
```

and next I write some code to read XML

```cs
XmlDocument cc = new XmlDocument();
cc.Load("wc.config");
XmlNodeList wc_value = cc.SelectNodes("configuration/work.config[@name='A']");

foreach (XmlNode wc_text in wc_value)
{
    String Text2 = wc_text.InnerText;
}
```

but `Text2` is null; why, and how do I have it not null?

And next I want to change name="B" value="999", how do I do that?

Comment: Your path `configuration/work.config[@name='A']` doesn't make sense as the `work.config` element does not have any attributes, it doesn't have any `name` attribute. So perhaps you want `configuration/work.config/variable[@name='A']` as the XPath. On the other hand you then try to access the `InnerText` of the selected nodes while all your `variable` elements are empty elements, meaning even if you fix the path the `InnerText` is empty. So it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Your `variable` elements dont not have text, that's the reason you are getting `null`.

Your variable elements have 2 attributes: `name` and `value`.

In order to get the value of the attribute:

```
string txt = wc_text.Attributes["name"].Value
```

Set value:

```
wc_text.Attributes["name"].Value = "foo".
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to XML to get or set value of any element or attribute based on condition as below:

*include namespace System.Xml.Linq in your using directives to use XDocument*

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("wc.config");

    foreach (XElement variableElement in doc.Descendants("variable"))
    {
        if (variableElement.Attribute("name").Value == "A")
        {
            variableElement.Attribute("value").Value = "";
        }
        else if (variableElement.Attribute("name").Value == "B")
        {
            variableElement.Attribute("value").Value = "999";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem begins in this line.

```
"configuration/work.config[@name='A']"
```

`work.config` attribute doesn't have an attribute called `name`. Following is what you actually required.

```
"configuration/work.config/variable[@name='A']"
```

Similarly, with the path fixed as above, the following line would still return empty string as you are reading the `InnerText` of the node.

```
String Text2 = wc_text.InnerText;
```

What you would need is to read the `Value` attribute of the node.

```
String Text2 = wc_text.Attributes["value"].Value;
```

If your intention is to Read and Update Value Attribute of a particular node, an easier approach would be to use XDocument.

```
// Assuming there are no duplicate names. You need to change accordingly the Queries if there are duplicates
public void UpdateKey(XDocument document,string key,string value)
{
    var node = document.Descendants("variable").First(x=>(string)x.Attribute("name")==key);
    node.Attribute("value").Value = value;
}

public string ReadKey(XDocument document, string key)
{
    return document.Descendants("variable").First(x=>(string)x.Attribute("name")==key).Attribute("value").Value;
}
```

Now, you could use it as

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xml);
var ValueOfA = ReadKey(doc,"A");
var oldValueOfB = ReadKey(doc,"B");
UpdateKey(doc,"B","999");
var newValueOfB = ReadKey(doc,"B");
```

Answer (score 0):

> LINQ to XML

```
void Main()
{

    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"e:\temp\wc.config");

    // read attributes
    foreach (var leaf in xmlDoc.Descendants("variable"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(leaf.Attributes("name").FirstOrDefault().Value);
        Console.WriteLine(leaf.Attributes("value").FirstOrDefault().Value);
    }

    // modify value of the attribute
    var attr = xmlDoc.Descendants("variable")
        .Where(d => (string)d.Attribute("name").Value == "B");
    attr.Attributes("value").FirstOrDefault().Value = "999";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath language:

```
var xmlString = @"<configuration>
    <work.config>
        <variable name='A' value='001' />
        <variable name='B' value='002' />
        <variable name='C' value='003' />
    </work.config>
</configuration>";

var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlString);
var variables = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//variable");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("C:\\config.xml");
            XmlNodeList list= doc.SelectNodes("configuration/work.config/variable");
            foreach (XmlNode item in list)
            {
                if (item.Attributes["name"].InnerText == "B")
                {
                    item.Attributes["value"].InnerText = "999";
                }
            }
```